# Programmatically WPF listbox.ItemsSource update

Tags: c#, wpf

I am doing a program like messenger that has all the contacts in a listbox with the relative states of the contacts.
Cyclic I get a xml with the contacts were updated over time, then updates the states within a class of binding called "Contacts".

The class Contacts has a filter to display only certain contacts by their state, "online, away, busy,.. " but not offline, for example ....

Some code:

```
public class Contacts : ObservableCollection<ContactData>
{
    private ContactData.States _state = ContactData.States.Online | ContactData.States.Busy;
    public ContactData.States Filter { get { return _state; } set { _state = value; } }
    public IEnumerable<ContactData> FilteredItems
    {
        get { return Items.Where(o => o.State == _state || (_state & o.State) == o.State).ToArray(); }
    }
    public Contacts()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://localhost/contact/xml/contactlist.php");
        foreach (ContactData data in ContactData.ParseXML(doc)) Add(data);
    }
}
```

Update part:

```
    void StatusUpdater(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContactData[] contacts = ((Contacts)contactList.Resources["Contacts"]).ToArray<ContactData>();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://localhost/contact/xml/status.php");
        foreach (XElement node in doc.Descendants("update"))
        {
            var item = contacts.Where(i => i.UserID.ToString() == node.Element("uid").Value);
            ContactData[] its = item.ToArray();
            if (its.Length > 0) its[0].Data["state"] = node.Element("state").Value;
        }
        contactList.ListBox.ItemsSource = ((Contacts)contactList.Resources["Contacts"]).FilteredItems;
    }
```

[image: Xaml Editor]

My problem is that when ItemsSource reassigns the value of the listbox, the program lag for a few seconds, until it has finished updating contacts UI (currently 250 simulated).

How can I avoid this annoying problem?

Edit:
I tried with Thread and after with BackgroundWorker but nothing is changed...
When i call Dispatcher.Invoke lag happen.

Class ContactData

```
public class ContactData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public enum States { Offline = 1, Online = 2, Away = 4, Busy = 8 }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int UserID 
    {
        get { return int.Parse(Data["uid"]); }
        set { Data["uid"] = value.ToString(); NotifyPropertyChanged("UserID"); }
    }
    public States State 
    {
        get { return (States)Enum.Parse(typeof(States), Data["state"]); }
        //set { Data["state"] = value.ToString(); NotifyPropertyChanged("State"); }
        //correct way to update, i forgot to notify changes of "ColorState" and "BrushState"
        set 
        { 
            Data["state"] = value.ToString(); 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("State");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ColorState");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BrushState");
        }
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
    public void Set(string name, string value) 
    {
        if (Data.Keys.Contains(name)) Data[name] = value;
        else Data.Add(name, value);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Data");
    }
    public Color ColorState { get { return UserStateToColorState(State); } }
    public Brush BrushState { get { return new SolidColorBrush(ColorState); } }
    public string FullName { get { return Data["name"] + ' ' + Data["surname"]; } }

    public ContactData() {}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        try { return FullName; }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); return base.ToString(); }
    }
    Color UserStateToColorState(States state)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case States.Online: return Colors.LightGreen;
            case States.Away: return Colors.Orange;
            case States.Busy: return Colors.Red;
            case States.Offline: default: return Colors.Gray;
        }
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }  

    public static ContactData[] ParseXML(XDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        var result = from entry in xmlDocument.Descendants("contact")
        select new ContactData { Data = entry.Elements().ToDictionary(e => e.Name.ToString(), e => e.Value) };
        return result.ToArray<ContactData>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed a similar software: a huge contact list with data (presence and other stuff) updating quite frequently.
The solution I used is different: instead of updating the whole itemssource everytime, that is quite expensive, implement a ViewModel class for each contact. The ViewModel class should implement INotifiyPropertyChanged.
At this point when you parse the XML, you update the ContactViewModel properties and this will trigger the correct NotifyPropertyChanged events that will update the correct piece of UI.
It might be expensive if you update a lot of properties  for a lot of contacts at the same time, for that you can implement some kind of caching like:
contactViewModel.BeginUpdate()
contactViewModel.Presence = Presence.Available;
..... other updates
contactViewModel.EndUpdate(); // at this point trigger PropertyCHanged events.

Another point:
keep a separate ObservableCollection bound to the ListBox and never change the itemssource property: you risk losing the current selection, scrollposition, etc.
dynamically add/remove elements from the collection bound to the listbox.

Buon divertimento e in bocca al lupo :-)

Comment: Let me see... for now i simple voting you up :D

Comment: I added INotifyPropertyChanged and implemented it, so like the Contacts Class (ObservableCollection) implement it for the filter part... but still no update (post updated)

Comment: You should never reassign the items source property. Every time you do it, you destroy all the graphic elements and WPF must rebuild all the visuals from scratch. Remove tha line of code and rely only on the InotifyPropertyChanged implemented on contactdata, or better yet on a wrapper (view model) around contact data. Using a virtualizingstackpanel can help, but not if you reassign every time the items source.

Comment: One further note: I've seen that of the comments says that there might be too many elements in the template for each contact. That's not the case. In the contact list we implemented, each contact badge had tons of visual info.

Comment: I worked out my problem, i forgot to insert 2 property binded together, when i change the state, also i need to send update of ColorState and BrushState  for see if changed effectively. Thanks a lot (Grazie mille :P)

Answer (score 1):

Move the downloading and parsing of the contact status information to another thread.

Comment: Have you tried finding out where most of the time is being spend?

Comment: listbox.Items.Refresh(); this is lagged. |  
listbox.ItemsSource = source; lagged also. | 
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding some}"> is not updating...

Comment: It feels like the amount of UI elements in the listbox is too large. Have you tried binding to a smaller set or using the VirtualizingStackPanel as ItemsPanel for the listbox?

Comment: I can make an alternative template to show only name and status, is it a test i haven't made...

Answer (score 0):

The line where you assigning the ItemsSource I would put in another thread, but remember about invoking or you're gonna have irritating errors.

Comment: Is the invoking part lagged, it come back to the main thread.

Comment: Well then possibly you need a different approach, try setting the datacontext of the listbox to your contacts observablecollection and in your wpf specify the binding. If this is a list of contacts then I would think that the list won't change much, only the status of the contacts will, so possibly the better approach would be to make FilteredItems as ObservableCollection and only change those updated ? A bit more effort but probably that will help.

Comment: It is part of a datacontext, and the fist bind is done via xaml code. But after some try, listbox still don't update visual if i don't call Items.Refresh() (lagged also)

Comment: I can't see the whole of your xaml but when you assign the itemssource from code then you overwrite your binding. So you overwrite your binding and just re-populate the whole listbox on each update. If you want to avoid the lag then I can see no other option but to change your approach of displaying the contacts.